# VBA - Initialize a String Array using a reference to other String variables

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to build an array whose elements are essentially variable names of other Dim Strings. I was just wondering about how to do this in VBA.

Example -

```
    Dim A1 As String
    Dim A2 As String
    Dim A3 As String

    Dim arrVarNames(3) As String
```

I tried initializing the declared array by coding as

```
     arrVarNames(3) = (A1,A2,A3).
```

but it did not work.

Then something like

```
    arrVarNames() = {A1,A2,A3}.
```

but it did not work either.

I could not find any examples online. So, please let me know the correct  way to do this.

Comment: You want an array of variable *names*, or an array of the variables themselves?  An array of variable names isn't going to be of much use, since there's no straightforward way in VBA to convert those names to values.   Might help to explain what you're trying to do with that array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to store the contents of the variables then this will work:

```
arrVarNames(0) = A1
arrVarNames(1) = A2
arrVarNames(2) = A3
```